# why am I getting 304 status code trying to get gif pic from cache

Tags: python, django, get, gif

I made a blog on Django and added images to form. While I add .jpg or .png pics I have now problem, evrth works, but once I try to add a .gif pic - it doesn't add to post. Another interesting fact, that when I try to edit this post and add that very .gif pic or any other .gif - it works.

when I press post button I see next logs:

```
[21/Jun/2022 19:03:04] "POST /create/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Jun/2022 19:03:05] "GET /profile/Natuska/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6925
[21/Jun/2022 19:03:05] "GET /media/cache/27/b6/27b6ff73a4d6cea2aa42a8ff16d888b6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/Jun/2022 19:03:05] "GET /media/cache/3a/11/3a11ddc3f6d23b024579611a813df2f4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/Jun/2022 19:03:10] "GET /profile/Natuska/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6925
[21/Jun/2022 19:17:09] "GET /posts/42/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2847
```

As I understand, I have some problems with cache. Obj not modified. But how it can be if it was just created

here is my views.py file:

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    template = 'posts/create_post.html'
    is_edit = False
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('posts:profile', username=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'is_edit': is_edit
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

@login_required
def post_edit(request, post_id):
    template = 'posts/create_post.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    form = PostForm(
        request.POST or None,
        instance=post,
        files=request.FILES or None,
     )
    is_edit = True
    if request.user.id != post.author.id:
        return redirect('posts:post_detail', post_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('posts:post_detail', post_id)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'is_edit': is_edit
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

def profile(request, username):
author = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
post_list = author.posts.all()
post_count = post_list.count()

context = {
    'author': author,
    'post_count': post_count,
    'post_list': post_list,
}
context.update(posts_pagination(post_list, request))
return render(request, 'posts/profile.html', context)
```

I would be grateful for any tips. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 304 is an HTTP response to indicate that the (previously fetched) content is the same as before, which can be returned if the browser has passed along an `If-Modified-Since` header. Is this an actual _problem_?

Comment: yes, it is very actual! this is the problem. how it can be modified if it was just created?

Comment: The fact that the browser included that `If-Modified-Since` header suggests very strongly that _it_ (the browser) thinks it has seen those particular URLs/images before. I would suggest looking at the code that generates the `/media/cache/*` files and making sure they are truly unique.